# Make a cryptical fields in Model

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to create fields in Django models, which:

1) In Django Form, which renders my Model I have one fields (let it be "secret_key"), where I input very important key which nobody should know or see.

2) In my Django Model that field will be stored as cryptical string (for example, i inputed 12345, it will be stored as *9h^%)

3) When I will need to use that field in my web site, I need to get that field from Model (Model.secret_key) as 12345, not as *9h^%

Thank you in advance.

**UPD:**

i need to do it without "help" libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Withnail's answer is comprehensive, it provides information about "one-way" encryption, where I believe you want "two-way" encryption.

One-way encryption means storing some value **v1** as an encrypted value **e1**, in such a way that you could *never* determine **v1** from **e1**. But, if you were shown a new value **v2**, you could determine whether **v1** == **v2**.

Two-way (symmetric) encryption is storing some value **v1** in an encrypted form **e1** that CAN be backtracked, if you know the key used to encrypt it. This is less secure, because if somebody knows the key, they can decode your data. But, if you had a column of your database encrypted like this, and stored your secret key outside of the DB, an attacker could not decode your column with the DB alone.

There's a great library for this already called [Django Fernet Fields](https://github.com/orcasgit/django-fernet-fields) that I think is exactly what you want. It uses your Django project's SECRET_KEY to encrypt and decrypt modelfields, while letting you use them regularly in your templates.

Comment: yes, exactly I need "two-way" encryption, thank you!

Comment: Only one problem - Django Fernet Fields  is for Django 1.8+, my project is on 1.6. There is such things for Django 1.6?

Comment: Not that I know of. As I see it, you have two options: you can fork django-fernet-fields and make it work for 1.6, or you can upgrade your project. If you have the power I would upgrade your project -- there are a lot of libraries that only work on 1.8 and on.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for hashing.

The main implementation of hashing inside django is for user passwords, and you could [reuse the existing password hashers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/)

Using a very simple and *not at all secure* example.

```
import hashlib

a = hashlib.md5('This is just a test').hexdigest()

b = hashlib.md5('This is just a test').hexdigest()

a
Out[33]: 'df0a9498a65ca6e20dc58022267f339a'

b
Out[34]: 'a87edc4866a7e4257e5912ba9735d20e'

a == b

Out[35]: True
```

using the Django [source code as an example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py), you could override your save method / similar to hash your field on save or retrieval.

```
def make_password(password, salt=None, hasher='default'):
    """
    Turn a plain-text password into a hash for database storage
    Same as encode() but generate a new random salt. If password is None then
    return a concatenation of UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX and a random string,
    which disallows logins. Additional random string reduces chances of gaining
    access to staff or superuser accounts. See ticket #20079 for more info.
    """
    if password is None:
        return UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX + get_random_string(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_SUFFIX_LENGTH)
    hasher = get_hasher(hasher)

    if not salt:
        salt = hasher.salt()

    return hasher.encode(password, salt)
```

This function is then used [here in the password/users model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8b2515a450ef376b9205029090af0a79c8341bd7/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py),

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
        self._password = raw_password
```

and here when the password is being checked:

```
def check_password(self, raw_password):
    """
    Return a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
    hashing formats behind the scenes.
    """
    def setter(raw_password):
        self.set_password(raw_password)
        # Password hash upgrades shouldn't be considered password changes.
        self._password = None
        self.save(update_fields=["password"])
    return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
```